# Potencia com For ou While

Tags: java, c#

preciso de uma ajudinha, como calculo a potencia utilizando o **for** ou **while**, não quero utilizar a função Math.Pow()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

c#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Base: ");
    int myBase = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Potencia: ");
    int myPow = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    int result = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < myPow; i++) result *= myBase;

    Console.WriteLine($"{myBase}^{myPow} = {result}");

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Versão LINQ para potencias maior que zero:

```
int result = Enumerable.Repeat(myBase, myPow).Aggregate((a, b) => a * b);
```

Comment: Muito obrigada!

Answer (score 1):

Potência é multiplicar uma parada várias vezes ela mesma. Faz aí um caso base que faz o número elevado a `1` com `for` ou `while` depois tenta generalizar, taca o caso do 0 também. Tem dois livros bem legais que explicam um jeito bom essas paradas de dividir problemas, tá em inglês e usam umas coisas meio bizarras pra quem não curte recursão. Mas dá uma olhada no "Structure and interpretation of computer programs", vê pelo menos até o cap 2 ou 3, ele é meio difícil, também tem o "How to design programs", esse daqui é mais fácil.

Comment: Muito obrigada!